# How to fix No sound on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: audio, ubuntu-18.04, soundcard

1) I've been using Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10 dual boot for some months now. Today suddenly my sound stopped working on Ubunutu. Activities -> Sound menu shows only "Dummy Output". All fine on Windows though.

2) Output of lsmod is:

```
rohit@rohitUb18043LTS:~$ lsmod | grep snd_
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_soc_dmic           16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   118784  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_soc_hdac_hdmi      32768  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    73728  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_byt      24576  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof                98304  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc,sof_pci_dev
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_hda_ext_core       28672  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    32768  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,sof_pci_dev
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,sof_pci_dev
snd_soc_core          237568  5 snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_dmic
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     57344  1
snd_hda_intel          53248  2
snd_intel_nhlt         20480  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         131072  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           90112  10 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102400  10 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    86016  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
rohit@rohitUb18043LTS:~$
```

3) I installed all updates from Software updater but no luck.

4) No change by using: sudo alsa force-reload

5) Looking around, found this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059619/sound-card-shown-as-dummy-output-in-ubuntu-18-04 . User says found the "active profile was off" and links to a solution on this forum (https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=268499). I am pasting the output of the four commands as per that link:

```
rohit@rohitUb18043LTS:~$ sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*
[sudo] password for rohit: 
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  gdm        1505 F.... pulseaudio
                     rohit      1878 F.... pulseaudio
rohit@rohitUb18043LTS:~$ pacmd list-cards
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xb4000000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0fb9"
        device.product.name = "GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
rohit@rohitUb18043LTS:~$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max request: 344 KiB
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 2000,00 ms
    module: 15
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
rohit@rohitUb18043LTS:~$ pacmd list-sink-inputs
0 sink input(s) available.
rohit@rohitUb18043LTS:~$
```

6) I tried the suggested command but it says "No such profile".

```
rohit@rohitUb18043LTS:~$ pacmd set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
No such profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
rohit@rohitUb18043LTS:~$
```

Please help - how do I proceed?

Comment: Update: I also tried the steps to remove and reload the drivers as per this link below - see answer by Roberto Gimenez : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081748/no-sound-on-ubuntu-18-04 . No luck!

Comment: Update 2: Also tried pacmd set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1 output:hdmi-stereo and the profile was set. But the Settings -> Sound shows as blank and no use. Tried same thing for the "output:hdmi-surround" and "output:hdmi-surround71" profiles. So reverted to "off" profile.

Comment: Update 3: Never fixed it. Thankfully 20.04LTS came out and without waiting for the full 20.04.1 release, I upgraded and thankfully that worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit the file /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and add the following lines:

**options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0**

**options snd-hda-intel model=laptop-amic enable=yes**

The first line is to enable the speaker, the second for the internal microphone.

Good luck!

Got this answer from Reddit. Worked like a charm for me!

Link : https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/fltlrl/no_sound_on_acer_swift_3_with_kernel_53/

Comment: Update: Started facing problem on Ubuntu 20.04LTS also. Followed your suggestion with only first line added. Its working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: HI, I have same problem in Ubuntu 22.04! I tried to add options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop-amic enable=yes  but I have read only file of alsa-base.conf     Would you please suggest me how to solve sound problem in Ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 8):

Similar issue with "Dummy Sound" on Ubuntu 18.04 also with a NVIDIA card. This solved it for me:

1. Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as root and add `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0`
2. Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` as root and add `blacklist snd_soc_skl` at the end of the file.
3. After making these changes, reboot your system.

More details (and credits): https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. As commented in my above update, I upgraded to 20.04LTS and for now the issue is fixed. But will come back to this if (hopefully not!) required. Cheers.

Comment: Update: Started facing problem on Ubuntu 20.04LTS also. Followed part of your suggestion - only dmic_detect line added, no black listing. Its working now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and tried the solution given by @maartenor without success.

Eventually I got the sound back by upgrading linux kernel to the last [HWE stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), for me it was *4.15.0-106-generic* to *5.3.0-59-generic*.

The command to do this :

```
$ sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

1. Open your terminal
2. sudo apt update && sudo apt install alsamixer
3. run alsamixer in your terminal.
4. press arrow right til you go to sound option (if headphone go to HEADPHONES bar).
5. press M to unmute.
6. press up/down to adjust the volume.
7. press Esc to exit alsamixer.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps worked very reliably. It does not fix the audio-losing-after-suspend issue permanently, but instantly as a command to run after back from suspend.

Use **lspci** to get the audio card location (0000:00:1f.3). On my machine,

```
$ lspci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H110 ...
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel ...
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset ...
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset ...
```

Then, (make sure the directories below exist)

```
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/remove
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

I believe the audio driver/hardware is stuck. So we remove the device driver, and rescan the PCI bus to get audio back.

Answer (score 0):

i found answer above not work on my computer, and i solve this problem by accidient , this is script i use , most same as answer above, but at last, u need mute then unmute auidio. sleep a short moment after command is necessary here if you put script in sh file then excute it , use sh -c is for  file redirection for root

```
REST=0.5
#make sure Audio always actived
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys/bus/pci/rescan'
sleep $REST
DEVICE_ID=$(lspci -D | grep Audio | awk '{print $1}')
sleep $REST
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/remove'
sleep $REST
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys/bus/pci/rescan'
sleep $REST
#mute then unmute to restart audio
amixer -D pulse sset Master mute
sleep $REST
amixer -D pulse sset Master unmute
```